# Does a <button> TYPE have to be defined?

Tags: html, button, semantics

When using the button tag, does the type attribute have to be defined, or is it semantic to just have?

```
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't have to specify it, it defaults to the value `submit`.

See [the HTML 4.x specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.5):

```
type        (button|submit|reset) submit -- for use as form button --
                                  ^^^^^^ default value
```

Compare with the action attribute for forms where it says #REQUIRED instead of giving a default value.

```
action      %URI;          #REQUIRED -- server-side form handler --
```

Comment: What would be considered the most semantic way to set a link on a button tag?

    <a href="#"><button>Click Me</button></a>

    <button><a href="#>Click Me</a></button>

    <button onclick="location.href='#'">Click Me</button>

Comment: @rick — `<a class="looks-like-a-button" href="foo">Text Content</a>` (The options you listed are, respectively, invalid, invalid and unnecessarily dependant on JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

As @Quentin’s answer explains, the `type` attribute is not required and it defaults to `submit`. There is no change to this in HTML5. However, the situation is slightly more complicated.

If the element appears outside any `form` element, the above still applies, but there is no form to submit. HTML5 clarifies this by describing the functionality so that it becomes clear that if there is no “form owner” (either an enclosing `form` element or a `form` element explicitly associated with the `button` element with an HTML5 attribute), there is no action – except as programmed with scripting, of course.

In effect, this means that outside a `form` element, a `button` element defaults to `type=button` functionally. This implies that if a `button` element that has `type` defaulted changes its context (e.g., gets wrapped inside a `form` element), its functionality changes. Therefore, for clarity and safety, it is better to explicitly specify the `type` attribute, e.g. `<button type=button>` or `<button type=submit>`.